# Is there a way to get the site_url in HTML code?

Tags: email, site-url

I have a WordPress website and it sends some transactional emails to the users. I create the template using HTML and I've been wondering if there's a way to add the `<?php echo site_url() ?>` in there so I don't have to change it manually every time I create a new website.

I have already tried using the `<?php echo site_url() ?>` in there, but it won't work.

Here's a sample of the code I am using

```
<td><a href="http://domain.com/" target="_blank">Deals</a></td>
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thank you in advance for the help,
Kat

Comment: I am assuming that you are first preparing HTML and then sending mail using wp_mail().
If so then <?php echo site_url() ?> should work.
What may go wrong:
You added the php code in single(') quote

Comment: Please add the code you've tried to your question.  Also, when you say "I create the template using HTML", is your file's extension `.html` or `.php`?

Comment: It's actually through the standard editor WordPress provides. Instead of using the 'Visual' I am using the 'Text' to create it.

Comment: The code is added with two quotes. I add the email content through the standard wordpress editor, but I am using the 'Text' view in order to add the HTML code of the email template. So, it's a code full of tables, etc.

Comment: you can't use php in the post editor, create a simple [shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) to output the URL instead.

Comment: Would the shortcode allow me though to add the url in the 'a' attribute? I was under the impression that shortcodes are used in order to display something.

Comment: Shortcodes are PHP functions with a [few WordPress rules](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) thrown in. While many do, they are not required to display anything.